# ionic 2 update problems

Tags: ionic2, upgrade

I'm trying to update my current ionic version `2.0.0-beta.32` to the latest version.

1) I runned the command : `sudo npm install -g ionic`

2) I runned the command : `npm outdated`

```
Package                                  Current         Wanted  Latest  Location
@angular/common                       2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/common
@angular/compiler                     2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/compiler
@angular/core                         2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/core
@angular/forms                             0.2.0          0.2.0   2.4.8  @angular/forms
@angular/http                         2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/http
@angular/platform-browser             2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/platform-browser
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic     2.0.0-rc.4     2.0.0-rc.4   2.4.8  @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
angular2-jwt                              0.1.17         0.1.17  0.1.28  angular2-jwt
del                                        2.2.0          2.2.0   2.2.2  del
es6-shim                                  0.35.0         0.35.0  0.35.3  es6-shim
gulp-watch                                 4.3.5          4.3.5  4.3.11  gulp-watch
ionic-angular                      2.0.0-beta.10  2.0.0-beta.10   2.0.1  ionic-angular
ionic-native                               1.3.2          1.3.2   2.5.1  ionic-native
reflect-metadata                           0.1.3          0.1.3  0.1.10  reflect-metadata
run-sequence                               1.1.5          1.1.5   1.2.2  run-sequence
rxjs                                5.0.0-beta.6   5.0.0-beta.6   5.2.0  rxjs
zone.js                                   0.6.26         0.6.26   0.7.7  zone.js
```

3) then I runned the command : `sudo npm install ionic-angular@latest`. Here I got this error :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "ionic-angular@latest"
npm ERR! node v4.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@0.2.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@2.0.1 wants @angular/common@2.2.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 wants @angular/common@2.2.1

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/ThePennyInc/penny-mobile-app/npm-debug.log
```

Any help please !

Comment: There is no beta-32. From the `npm outdated` command it looks like beta-10

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of breaking changes from beta to the latest ionic version including file structure and app scripts.
Check [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0) fro steps to upgrade from Beta version. Though it says to RC0, you could follow the steps to upgrade your project by starting a new project and copying the files.
There may be errors in the code due to breaking changes in different versions.

To verify,
[Here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) is the latest package.json for the current ionic version.